# Javascript: Trying to change the text (/ or call a function) in an iFrame, from a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html

***Ok! I figured it out! Thanks alot you guys (thanks algiecas)! The problem was that I wasn't testing it on Localhost, I can just edit the text now, and It's all good! Can't make the function to work it seems.. But I CAN edit the text now in the iFrame, so my problem is solved!***

I have searched all over the web, but cant seem to get this working.. I'm trying to use:

-`frames["FRAME"].document.getElementById("txtNewsHtm")` 
-`document.getElementById('FRAME').contentWindow.updateNews();`
-`FRAME.txtNewsHtm.innerHTML = 'test1';`

All these ways to try and change a `<p id = 'txtNewsHtm'>` inside of an iFrame (home.html), thats included into index.html. I also have a .js file where I keep most of my code.

I've tried to use a function inside of the iFrame (point nr 2), didn't work, i've tried to access the `<p>` directly from the .js file (points nr 1 and 3), didn't work. I've tried ALOT of other things as well, but i just can't make it too work.

Does anyone has any advice for me? Please help me out here.

I'm making language buttons for on a website that, through javascript, dynamically change the text on the website, it works for index.html, but I can't seem to get it to work for the iFrame home.html. Seems like home.html doesn't want to 'listen' to the .js file OR index.html.

Thanks!

Comment: Are both `home.html` and `index.html` on the same domain?

Comment: @Town: Yes, they are, also on the root.

Comment: Ok, what does your error console say? (`ctrl-shift-J > Console` in Chrome).

Comment: Please show your HTML for both pages

Comment: @Town: Nothing really related to this problem.. I get a couple of errors relating to jwplayer, but that's completely apart from this problem. I tried Alex Ackerman's tip, and now it shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined", in other words, the iFrame is undefined? Maybe that's because it's not loaded yet?

@algiecas: What do you want to see? There is alot of HTML to be pasted here.. Do you want to see the JavaScript code?

Comment: There might be a simple typo in your HTML, just wanted to check it out (the parts related to your question - frame and paragraph)

Comment: Ok I've further checked out the suggestion you made on checking the error console and I'm getting this error now (I'm working locally ofcourse):
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///.../home.html from frame with URL file:///.../index.html#. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Comment: Ok, I've added the files, not completely though, to my original post.

Comment: Try to test your pages on server or put it somewhere on localhost. Maybe these file:///... are breaking something...

Comment: @algiecas: Very nice! I've used 127.0.0.1 to connect to the page, now i'm getting this error (maybe I need to relocate the function updateNews()? I now put the function out of the loaded() function, still getting the same error.. How do I make it so that the .js file finds the function?): `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'updateNews'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be executing javascript from the page in the frame itself. Try using top instead of window (copying the code from Alex Ackerman):

```
function setFrameHTML() {
   top.frames[0].document.getElementById('txtNewsHtm').innerHTML = 'test';
}
```

EDIT:

Ok, so after some discussion it turns out, that you need to test you HTML pages from localhost (or remote server), not opening file from the file system (file:///...)

Second thing: you are calling `updateNews();` before the function is declared. Move it after the function declaration. The same thing with `changeText();`

Comment: Getting the errors: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementById' of undefined` ////// `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///.../home.html from frame with URL file:///.../index.html#. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

Answer (score 1):

Try this for a test.
In parent .js file create a function

```
function setFrameHTML() {
   window.frames[0].document.getElementById('txtNewsHtm').innerHTML = 'test';
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Still doesn't do anything to txtNewsHtm's innerHTML :/

Comment: Should I copy that in a comment? That seems a bit too much.. Sorry first time asking a question on this site :)..

Comment: @Tom: Edit your question and insert the HTML/script in there.

Comment: perhaps the document within the frame is not ready when you try to perform the action.

Comment: I've added the files, not completely though, to my original post.